# Unable to boot into Windows after deleting Windows entry in boot menu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I was  using Ubuntu 12.04.
After installing Windows 7, I wasn't able to boot Ubuntu.
So, I installed EasyBCD in Windows 7 and added grub2 Entry.
While, playing with EasyBCD, I deleted Windows loader and restarted my machine.

Now, How can I recover Ubuntu?

Comment: To Clarify, the MBR points to the windows boot system. The windows boot system only lists Ubuntu.  Ubuntu starts up grub and displays Ubuntu and windows.  Ubuntu boots fine. Selecting windows from grub causes a boot failure.

Comment: @hao-nguyen Were you trying to delete windows entry in grub using EasyBCD on WIndows? EasyBCD only customizes windows Bootloader. It can't customize grub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run Ubuntu on a part of your disc, and it is still runnable, (Not destroyed!) then try to repair the grub boot manager I use the nice little tool 'Boot-Repair', which is in the Ubuntu repository. You can even use it on a USB stick.

[Guide Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 1):

You will to need to restore the Master Boot Record for Windows 7 Again.

**How to run the Bootrec.exe tool**

1)Put the Windows Windows 7 media in the DVD drive, and then start the computer.

2)Press a key when you are prompted.

3)Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard, or an input method, and then click Next.

4)Click Repair your computer.

5)Select the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.

6)In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.

7)Type Bootrec.exe, and then press Enter.

If that doesnt do anything try with

Bootrec.exe /FixMbr

This option writes a Windows 7 MBR to the system partition. It does not overwrite the existing partition table. Use this option when you must resolve MBR corruption issues, or when you have to remove nonstandard code from the MBR

Answer (score 0):

Hei,
you should take this little [Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) so it's easier to help you in the future.

Maybe this will help you http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dualboot I would suggest to reinstall Ubuntu and Windows and follow this guide --> http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony or this one --> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look into a handy tool called [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This should help you fix your bootloader.